# Adding event .change() to newly added fields

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

So, I have a rails application where I have jquery do a `.change()` on the id of the field which is `recipe_ingredients_attributes_0_quantity`.

Then using ryan bate's [nested forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2), I can add a new field with an id containing a timestamp instead of 0 as shown before.  My question is how can I add an `.change()` event to this new field?

**Solution:**

Here is what I did.

```
function add_fields(link, association, content) {
    var new_id = new Date().getTime();
    var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g")
    $(link).up().insert({
        before: content.replace(regexp, new_id)
    });
    var elemId = "#{association}_attributes_#{new_id}_number"
    $('elemId').change(function() {
       /* do whatever */
   }
}
```

Comment: What functionality do you want to do when the event happens?

Comment: So pretty much I want a user to add a new field and enter a number.  And I want it to automatically average all the numbers from the fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this above, but I figured I would put this below.  I worked out this based on guest271314's answer.  Here is what I did.

```
function add_fields(link, association, content) {
    var new_id = new Date().getTime();
    var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g")
    $(link).up().insert({
        before: content.replace(regexp, new_id)
    });
    var elemId = "#{association}_attributes_#{new_id}_number"
    $('elemId').change(function() {
       /* do whatever */
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is your issue event delegation?

If, so here is the JQuery:

```
//#newElem gets added to DOM sometime after initial page load
$(document).on("change", "#newElem", eventHandlerFxn);
```

Comment: The main problem is I don't know the new element id.  It is in the form of a timestamp such as `#attributes_12434525`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
function add_fields(link, association, content) {
  var new_id = new Date().getTime();
  var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g")
  $(link).up().insert({
    before: content.replace(regexp, new_id)
  });
  /* continuing user3352294's answer */
  $(document).on("change", "#newElem"+new_id, eventHandlerFxn);
}
```

Comment: I did something very much like this. Except that Id didn't seem to work.  I was able to get it to work using a modified id.  Check my post for details.

Answer (score 0):

The nested form will use a blue print to add a new HTML content. Hence, rather than associating the event on id (which would be unknown to you since its added dynamically), add the event on a particular class. The class would be the same in all nested fields.

Answer (score 0):

I would do `$(document).on("change", function(event){//do whatever here});`

This will trigger anytime there is a change event fired in the document.  I would recommend scoping it to your form so you only get the events from the form.  The reason you want to do this is because you bind events to the elements, if the element is loaded in dynamically you have to add it to the element when it is loaded.  If you don't know the id of the element you can use event delegation, because all events bubble up the DOM unless you stop the propagation using event object.  If you attach the event to the parent element all child elements events will bubble up to the parent unless you prevent the default behavior.